# "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present at java.util.Optional.get" in a Spock test using mocks

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, spock

I'm trying to write a groovy Unit Test for the following method:

```
public Set<ObjectName> getAll()
{

    return getMBeanServerConnection().map(mbsc ->
    {
        try
        {
            return mbsc.queryNames(null, null);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception was thrown: ", e);
            return Collections.<ObjectName>emptySet();
        }
    }).get();
}
```

The method calls the following:

```
    private Optional<MBeanServerConnection> getMBeanServerConnection()
{
    return virtualMachineHelper.getMb();
}
```

and then :

```
public Optional<MBeanServerConnection> getMb()
{
    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = getOmsVirtualMachine();
    if (virtualMachine == null)
    {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    try
    {
        Properties props = virtualMachine.getAgentProperties();
        String connectorAddress =
            props.getProperty(JMX_REMOTE_PROPERTY);

        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(connectorAddress);
        JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
        MBeanServerConnection mbsc = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
        return Optional.of(mbsc);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "An exception was thrown: ", e);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

which is just a method that forwards a call to mbsc.queryNames(null, null)

I'm trying to test that when calling getAll() then mbsc.queryNames(null, null) is called once.

I have the following code:

```
def virtualMachineHelperMock = Mock(VirtualMachineHelper)
def mBeanServerConnection = Mock(MBeanServerConnection)

ObjectNamesRepository objectNamesRepository = new ObjectNamesRepository(virtualMachineHelperMock)

void setup() {
    virtualMachineHelperMock.getMb() >> Optional.of(mBeanServerConnection)
}

def "when calling getAll then queryNames is called from mBeanServerConnection"() {
    when:
    objectNamesRepository.getAll()

    then:
    1 * mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(null, null)
}
```

But this gives the following error:

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

```
at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
at com.ullink.ulconsole.repository.ObjectNamesRepository.getAll(ObjectNamesRepository.java:73)
at com.ullink.ulconsole.repository.ObjectNamesRepositorySpec.GetAll(ObjectNamesRepositorySpec.groovy:32)
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code, e.g. `getMBeanServerConnection()`

Comment: Sure, I've edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because no stubbed response for the `mbsc.queryNames(null, null)` call is recorded, so the mock [returns the default value](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/interaction_based_testing.html#_default_behavior_of_mock_objects): `null`. And the [contract of `Optional.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) is as follows:

> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and
>   **if the result is non-null**, return an Optional describing the result.
>   **Otherwise return an empty Optional.**

You get an empty `Optional` from the `map()` call, hence the exception.

To fix this, you can stub the call in the same interaction, as described in [Spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing):

```
1 * mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(null, null) >> Collections.emptySet()
```